# Joomla 4 component and custom field

Tags: component, joomla-4

Good day.

I created a component using
https://blog.astrid-guenther.de/en/joomla-custom-fields-im-frontend-integrieren/
https://blog.astrid-guenther.de/en/joomla-frontend-editing/

When editing an entry in the admin panel, the value of the user field is saved.

When editing a record on the site, the value of the user field is not saved.

Tell me what could be the problem?

 My component https://github.com/antarey/com_test1

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component needs to implement `Joomla\CMS\Fields\FieldsServiceInterface`. It has two methods:
`getContexts()` which returns an array with contexts as keys and human readable titles as values. And `validateSection()` which allows mapping a provided "section" to another one. In this case section refers to a part of context without component prefix. When plugins are triggered in your component during frontend editing,`com_test.form` context is used. You need to remap this to `com_test.test1` to match context used in backend. So your `validateSection()` method should look like this:

```
public function validateSection($section, $item = null)
{
    if ($section === 'form')
    {
        return 'test1';
    }

    return $section;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Sharky**
Thanks for showing me where to look.
It was necessary to add code

```
use Joomla\CMS\Fields\FieldsServiceInterface;
...
class Test1Component  ..,FieldsServiceInterface
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the code in the file - administrator\components\com_test1\src\Extension\Test1Component.php.

```
public function validateSection($section, $item = null)
{
    if ($section === 'form')
    {
        return 'test1';
    }

    return $section;
}

public function getContexts(): array
{
    Factory::getLanguage()->load('com_test1', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);

    $contexts = array(
        'com_test1.test1'    => Text::_('COM_CONTENT'),
        'com_test1.categories' => Text::_('JCATEGORY')
    );

    return $contexts;
}
```

Unfortunately, it didn't help